# Pass variable back to injected angular module?

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular-module that looks like this:

```
angular.module('simperiumAngular', []).
config(function(simperiumCred){
    console.log(simperiumCred)
//  var simperium = new Simperium('SIMPERIUM_APP_ID', { token : 'SIMPERIUM_ACCESS_TOKEN'});
})
```

How can I pass the constant simperiumCred from the main angular module, that the first module is injected into:

```
angular.module('todo', ['simperiumAngular']).
constant('simperiumCred','test').
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
  config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
    // This is an example of config block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
    // into config blocks.
  });
```

You can see this jsfiddle link for the [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/9GjYg/), how to inject something into config file.

Hope this is help!!

Comment: :) not really answering the question. I want to inject constants into my config.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. If what you want is to access a constant defined in another module, then this works for me:

```
var other = angular.module('other',[]);
other.constant('message', {message: 'Hello World'});

var sample =  angular.module('sample',['other']);

sample.config(['message', function(message){
    alert(message.message);
}]);
```

Comment: No, the other way around. I want to define the constant in sample and do a config on other. (the difference being what module get's injected to what)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a constant by the way.